# ImportError: Could not import PIL.Image

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, python-imaging-library

I am trying to build a neural network mostly based off an online tutorial. However, I keep getting a re-occuring theme of

```
raise ImportError('Could not import PIL.Image. '
ImportError: Could not import PIL.Image. The use of `load_img` requires PIL.
```

I've tried a lot of things from other questions similar to this. I've tried uninstalling and re-installing pillow in conda. Then I tried re-installing the package on the Pycharm Project Interpreter and then the terminal. None of it seems to work

As a reference, here is my code

```
import numpy as np
import keras
import sys
from keras import backend as K
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Activation
from keras.layers.core import Dense, Flatten
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras.metrics import categorical_crossentropy
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.layers.normalization import BatchNormalization
from keras.layers.convolutional import *
import PIL
from keras_preprocessing import image

train_path = "D:\Proj1\Images_AP\Train"
valid_path = "D:\Proj1\Images_AP\Valid"


train_batches = ImageDataGenerator().flow_from_directory(train_path, target_size=(2500, 2048), classes=['Disease', 'No_Disease'], batch_size=100)
valid_batches = ImageDataGenerator().flow_from_directory(valid_path, target_size=(2500, 2048), classes=['Disease', 'No_Disease'], batch_size=25)


model = Sequential([
    Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(2500, 2048, 1)),
    Flatten(),
    Dense(2, activation='softmax'),
])

model.compile(Adam(lr=.0001), loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit_generator(train_batches, steps_per_epoch=160,
                    validation_data=valid_batches, validation_steps=160, epochs=160, verbose=2)




#from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
```

Comment: could you please check whether it is correctly installed or not?

Comment: Where would the correct version of PIL be installed from?

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/2.2.1/

Comment: Yes, I just uninstalled and reinstalled pillow using pip install Pillow. I re-tried it but am still getting the same errors

Comment: but you are not even using it, remove it from the Import

Comment: Are you sure you're in the same interpreter (environment) where you installed it?

Comment: It gave me the error before I added the import. I added the import hoping that would fix it.

Comment: Yes, cause I installed the package using pycharms terminal and added it using the pycharm project interpreter.

Comment: @techNovice, Is your issue fixed after installing Pillow ?

Answer (score 1):

IF you are running in a Conda virtual environment this might apply. I had the same problem and realized that pillow had been installed with pip inside the conda virtual environment. You can verify this simply by doing `conda list | grep pillow`. To fix the problem I simply installed pillow via conda, like so `conda install pillow`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS, Python 3.6.9, Keras 2.0.6 and pycharm-community       2020.2.3.  I recently hit the same problem while running the **Classify ImageNet classes with ResNet50** example code from https://keras.io/api/applications/ within in PyCharm.  Just doing the following in a plain terminal outside PyCharm didn't help.

```
pip3 install pillow
```

But when I did it same but using PyCharm terminal, then it worked as the error went away and the code was able to compile and run.